# Difference many columns from a baseline column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, diff

I have a baseline column (`base`) in a pandas data frame and I want to difference all other columns `x*` from this column while preserving two groups `group1, group2`:

The easiest way is to simply difference by doing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'group2': [2, 2, 3, 4],
                   'base': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'x1': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'x2': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df['diff_x1'] = df['x1'] - df['base']
df['diff_x2'] = df['x2'] - df['base']

   group1  group2  base  x1  x2  diff_x1  diff_x2
0       0       2     0   3   5        3        5
1       0       2     1   4   6        3        5
2       1       3     2   5   7        3        5
3       1       4     3   6   8        3        5
```

But I have hundreds of columns I need to do this for, so I'm looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: As you may know, `df.drop([col_list], axis=1)` will drop specified columns. Then `df.sub(df['base'], axis=0)` will subtract that column from each individual column of your df.

Comment: Btw, when you say "preserve two groups `group1,group2`", since you don't have any index, it can be efficient to `.set_index(['group1','group2'])` as a multiindex. instead of having to specially treat the columns at each step. Then they can never accidentally be stripped or dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract a Series from a dataframe column wise using the `sub` method with `axis=0`, which can save you from doing the subtraction for each column individually:

```
to_sub = df.filter(regex='x.*')  # filter based on your actual logic
pd.concat([
  df, 
  to_sub.sub(df.base, axis=0).add_prefix('diff_')
], axis=1)
#   group1  group2  base  x1  x2  diff_x1  diff_x2
#0       0       2     0   3   5        3        5
#1       0       2     1   4   6        3        5
#2       1       3     2   5   7        3        5
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `df.drop(..., axis=1)`. Then pass each remaining column of that dataframe into `sub(..., axis=0)`. Guarantees you catch all columns, and preserve their order, don't even need a regex.

```
df_diff = df.drop(['group1','group2','base'], axis=1).sub(df['base'], axis=0).add_prefix('diff_')

   diff_x1  diff_x2
0        3        5
1        3        5
2        3        5
3        3        5
```

Hence your full solution is:

```
pd.concat([df, df_diff], axis=1)

   group1  group2  base  x1  x2  diff_x1  diff_x2
0       0       2     0   3   5        3        5
1       0       2     1   4   6        3        5
2       1       3     2   5   7        3        5
3       1       4     3   6   8        3        5
```